# How do i make my css work for screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, wrapper, resolution, screen-resolution

At the moment my css will work on one resolution and then when I try and edit it with a screen with a different resolution, it changes it and doesn't look the same. I added a wrapper div to it, but its still doing it, can anybody help me see what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Here is the whole of my css:

```
#Wrapper {height: 100%;
width: 90%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 1%;
margin-left: auto;}

#Title_Background {background: #3399FF;
position: absolute;
height: 15%;
width: 98%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-left: 1%;
border-radius: 10px;}

#Title h1 {font-family: Arial;
font-size: 24px; 
color: black;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 20px;}

#img1 {position: absolute;
height: 2%;
width: 4%;
top: 22px;
left: 51px;}

#LeftNav {background: #3399FF;
position: absolute;
float: left;
clear: left;
height: 82%;
width: 9%;
top: 16%;
left: 0px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 1%;}

#LeftNav p {font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-left: 1%;
position: relative;
border: 3px solid #000000;
border-style: outset;}

.Inset p {position: relative;
border: 3px solid #000000;
border-style: inset !important;}

.Content {background: yellow;
position: absolute;
height: 60%;
width: 72%;
top: 250px;
left: 14%;
margin: 0 auto;}

.Content p {font-family: Arial;
font-size: 20px;
top: 200px;
text-align: center;}

#RightNav {background: #3399FF;
position: absolute;
float: right;
clear: right;
height: 82%;
width: 9%;
top: 16%;
right: 0px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 1%;}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you might want to look into "Responsive Design" 
Here is an article:
http://thinkvitamin.com/design/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design/
and you can get more via google, ect.

Short summary: Using the combination of a few techniques you can make your webpages available to a variety of resolutions.

The @media tag can help you target certain resolutions or ranges, and resize or change things to fit.

Comment: Was about to write a similar answer, but perhaps for this particular question just setting -say- `#wrapper { width: 960px; }` (instead of 90%) would do the trick? If not some additional info in the question would help.